# apt-get update explodes - public keys missing, how to add them?

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, repository, gnupg

I'm not able to `apt-get update` anymore, because of missing public keys.

```
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Ign:15 https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ InRelease         
Get:16 https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ Release [1.487 B]
Get:17 https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ Release.gpg [287 B]
Err:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
Err:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
Err:10 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
Ign:17 https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
E: The repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ Release: Detached signature file '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.videolan.org_pub_debian_stable_._Release.gpg' is in unsupported binary format
E: The repository 'https://download.videolan.org/pub/debian/stable ./ Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When I try to add them, I get the following error:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.xmyYXrwDlk/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13
gpg: key 7721F63BD38B4796: public key "Google Inc. (Linux Packages Signing Authority) <linux-packages-keymaster@google.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.xmyYXrwDlk/home:ungoogled_chromium.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 6BCA5E4DB84288D9: 2 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 02456C79B2FD48BF: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key D94AA3F0EFE21092: 3 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 871920D1991BC93C: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
gpg: Total number processed: 10
gpg:       skipped new keys: 10
```

How do I resolve these gpg issues?

Comment: Please add the output of `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` and `sudo grep -ir ungoogled /etc` with  `sudo apt-get update` to the question or upload to pastebin if long.

Comment: Yes sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/zBSTn3a6

Answer (score 3):

You have a bunch problems here.

To fix them use Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) application window as follows:

1. to disable the `ppa:webupd8team/java` (it does not provide [packages for 20.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) and discontinued) and `download.videolan.org` (it is outdated, last packages were from [2013, 2016](https://download.videolan.org/debian/stable/)) go to Other Software tab and then disable it.
2. to fix the GPG keys problem go to Authentication tab and remove other GPG keys to have this tab looking as follows

   [image: GPG keys]
3. close Software & Updates, do not allow it to run software list reload

Then open terminal to remove broken software lists and to add new GPG keys by the commands below:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

cd /tmp
wget -c http://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
sudo apt-key add linux_signing_key.pub

wget -c https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc
sudo apt-key add microsoft.asc

wget -c https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
sudo apt-key add ACCC4CF8.asc

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EB3E94ADBE1229CF
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys AB9660B9EB2CC88B
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
```

and finally run `sudo apt-get update` with optional `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (to get newest upgrades with dependencies).

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately, that didn't work. When I try to `apt-key add` the key, I get this error:

```
gpg: invalid key resource URL '/tmp/apt-key-gpghome.ZJDSiCWFY4/home:ungoogled_chromium.asc.gpg'
gpg: keyblock resource '(null)': General error
gpg: key 02456C79B2FD48BF: 1 signature not checked due to a missing key
[... truncated]
gpg: Total number processed: 6
gpg:       skipped new keys: 
```

I tried removing ungoogled chromium and restarted my computer, didn't change anything. I think the best option would be to completely reinstall Ubuntu again, wouldn't it?

Comment: See updated answer.